# Highstock Range Selector Buttons to PDF Export Dropdown

Tags: highcharts

I have been able to convert my range selector buttons in to a dropdown rather than displaying as a list. And seperately, adding the export to PDF/Image dropdown.

What i am now trying to achieve is integrate the range selector dropdown buttons in to the same dropdown as the Export, or vice versa.

Export:

```
exporting: {
    enabled: true,
    allowHtml: true,
    accessibility: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    buttons: {
        contextButtons: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
}
```

Range selector:

```
exporting: {
  buttons: {
    contextButton: {
      enabled: false
    },
    toggle: {
      text: 'Select range',
      align: 'left',
      height: 20,
      y: -3,
      theme: {
        'stroke-width': 0.5,
        stroke: '#000000',
        r: 2
      },
      menuItems: [{
        text: '1M',
        onclick: function() {
          this.rangeSelector.clickButton(0, true);
        }
      }, {
        text: '3M',
        onclick: function() {
          this.rangeSelector.clickButton(1, true);
        }
      }, {
        text: '6M',
        onclick: function() {
          this.rangeSelector.clickButton(2, true);
        }
      }, {
        text: 'YTD',
        onclick: function() {
          this.rangeSelector.clickButton(3, true);
        }
      }, {
        text: '1Y',
        onclick: function() {
          this.rangeSelector.clickButton(4, true);
        }
      }, {
        text: 'All',
        onclick: function() {
          this.rangeSelector.clickButton(5, true);
        }
      }]
    }
  }
},
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8rrotg5a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add default items to `menuItems` array:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            enabled: false
        },
        toggle: {
            ...,
            menuItems: [..., {
                    text: 'All',
                    onclick: function() {
                        this.rangeSelector.clickButton(5, true);
                    }
                },
                'separator',
                'viewFullscreen',
                'printChart',
                'separator',
                'downloadPNG',
                'downloadJPEG',
                'downloadPDF',
                'downloadSVG'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j7s8xgtr/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems